# Where to download Ruby MRI as zip instead of installer?

Tags: ruby

Where can one download the MRI version of Ruby as a zip file instead of an installer? I may be overlooking it, but I don't see such a thing on the [download page](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/).

This is for Windows XP. I forgot to specify that. Looking for the stand-alone binary (thought that part was obvious). Sorry for the omissions.

Comment: What do you mean by `zip`? What you only have to unzip, and then doubleclick and run? You didn't even write what OS you have. (Mac, Windows, Linux, etc.) 
An unzipped version will not even set your PATH environment variable, so you can only run it from its own folder.
Why not download the source and build it for yourself __THEN__ zip it?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want? Just the Ruby source code?

Comment: You should at least include the OS that you want the binaries for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Under `7-zip archives`

You will need an archive manager to extract the files.

Ruby executables are under `\bin\`. You might want extract it first, and add the extracted location to your system environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer. The downloads page at RubyInstaller.org has the [stand-alone archives](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).